# Ubuntu 18.04.4 restart randomly in live usb

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, lubuntu, mate

I created a bootable USB of Ubuntu 18.04.4 and booted from live USB. It restarts automatically after some time. I tried with the Ubuntu Mate also for the same version and the same problem with it also. My laptop has i7-9750H Nvidia 1650 MaxQ.

I tried with one earlier version of the Ubuntu i.e. Ubuntu 18.04.3 and I had no problem with that version and my laptop wasn't rebooting randomly. I suspect it to be a kernel issue. Anybody faced such a problem, how do I install Ubuntu Mate 18.04.4 on my laptop? Please help. Thanks

Note: I am trying to install ubuntu on the laptop which already has Windows 10 installed.

Comment: As you believe it's kernel related, why not install Ubuntu 18.04.1 which will install the GA kernel (4.15), then `sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade` which will upgrade your system to 18.04.4 but with the GA (4.15) kernel rather than HWE kernel. *You can also switch from HWE kernel to GA on your existing system I suppose, providing system stays up long enough to install before you reboot & use GA kernel, this advice applies equally to all flavors, 18.04.2 & later media use HWE by default*  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack